# How can I fetch parent table's value within a trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a PARENT table and a CHILD table.

```
PARENT
------
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL


CHILD
-----
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
PARENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
```

I want to create a trigger which does

- when a CHILD row inserted or updated
- check the NEW.NAME
- and if the NEW.NAME is NULL or EMPTY
- use PARENT's NAME as NEW.NAME

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables:

```
create table PARENT
(
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

create table CHILD
(
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PARENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER namecheck BEFORE INSERT ON CHILD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE parentname VARCHAR(255);

  IF NEW.NAME IS NULL OR NEW.NAME=''
  THEN
    SELECT NAME
    INTO @parentname
    FROM PARENT 
    WHERE ID=NEW.PARENT_ID;
    SET NEW.NAME = @parentname;
  END IF;    
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
mysql> insert into PARENT values ( 1,'phil' );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into CHILD values(1,'',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from CHILD;
+----+------+-----------+
| ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | phil |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

There's no error checking etc, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IFNULL**(see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)) for **NULL** only or **IF**(see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)) when you're going to include empty strings when setting the value for **NEW.NAME**.

**BEFORE INSERT** when you have to check the record first before inserting the record.

You can try the below query:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `checkIfNull`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `checkIfNull` BEFORE INSERT ON `CHILD` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SELECT `NAME` INTO @v_name FROM PARENT WHERE `ID` = new.PARENT_ID;
     SET new.NAME = IF(new.NAME IS NULL OR new.NAME = '',@v_name,new.NAME);
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The **IF** part checks if the new **NAME** contains a value, if *YES* the value would be as it is, if *NO* it will use the name of the **PARENT_ID** from the **PARENT** table.